# How to write multiple function of same variables to single function

Tags: python, flask

I am creating one flask application with two submit pages, variables remains same. How to create a unique function for the parent one so that  I can inherit to other. Here `submit_two` method is eveyrthing is same of `submit_one` except the render_template.

```
@app.route('/submit_one',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit_one():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    FirstName = request.form.get('FirstName')
    LastName = request.form.get('LastName')
  return render_template('submit_one.html')

@app.route('/submit_two',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit_one():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    FirstName = request.form.get('FirstName')
    LastName = request.form.get('LastName')
  return render_template('submit_two.html')

@app.route('/result_one',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def result_one():
  with open(filetoread) as fp:
    content = fp.read()
  return render_template('result_one.html', details=content)

@app.route('/result_two',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def result_two():
  with open(filetoread) as fp:
    content = fp.read()
  return render_template('result_two.html', details=content)
```

Comment: You can move the common code to a generic function which will be called by the two specific ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def formHandler(request_obj):
    FirstName = request_obj.form.get('FirstName')
    LastName = request_obj.form.get('LastName')
    return {"fname":FirstName ,"lname":LastName }



   @app.route('/submit_one',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def submit_one():
      if request.method == 'POST':
          formHandler(request_obj)
      return render_template('submit_one.html')

    @app.route('/submit_two',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def submit_one():
      if request.method == 'POST':
          formHandler(request_obj)
      return render_template('submit_two.html')
```

Something like that

Answer (score 1):

```
@app.route('/<var_name>',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit(var_name):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    FirstName = request.form.get('FirstName')
    LastName = request.form.get('LastName')

  if var_name == 'submit_two':
    render_template('submit_two.html')
  elif var_name == 'submit_one':
    return render_template('submit_one.html')
```

You can try this but it is not good practice to do so.